# Why might a Django admin form hang (or, how can I diagnose the problem)?

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django, I have a model tied to the admin. Whenever I try to add a new model instance, or update an existing one, the form hangs while trying to submit. Nothing is written to the log files, though. The models are nothing fancy, so they don't have any custom validation that may be causing, e.g., and infinite loop. Also, the hang only occurs on my production server, not on the staging server or my local development machine.

I've noticed the following error in the Apache log files, but I'm not sure if it's a symptom of my problem, or something else:

> Exception exceptions.TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in > ignored

What might be causing the hang? Or, since that's probably hard to answer without all the specifics of my setup and application, what's the best way to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Hard to tell, you should at least post your model/admin/form code, especially if you made any customizations... Do other forms behave well?

Comment: All the other forms work fine, as far as I know. There's not really much to the classes themselves, save for a few fields, and the old form customizations consist of changes to `list_display` and its ilk. There's not anything fancy going on in the models or admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I think this was just a performance issue. I'm using WSGI in daemon mode; reducing the number of WSGI processes seems to have eliminated the problem.